# How do you restore a particular table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, restore

One of our users has deleted a table by mistake. How can I restore only that table?

Comment: The answer to this problem would depend on 1. the table engine (myisam or innodb) you are using, and 2. the type of backup method that you are using (text backups or binary backups). If you can answer these two questions then only would I be able to tell you the exact method of restoring the table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MySQL, so don't have a straight line of directions. What I'd do is to restore the last backup (do you have one?) of the database on the same or a different server and copy the missing table table to the main on-line database.

PS: oh, and also remove the write permission for that user :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a backup dump of the DB, there's a nice article on the alternatives here. 
http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/on-restoring-a-single-table-from-mysqldump

Most commonly you want to extract the relevant data and exclude data on the rest of the tables.

If you have binlogs, you'll most likely need to create a temporary copy of the whole DB and replay from the last dump.

Comment: you can also easily extract specific tables (full with data, or only table definitions) from mysql dumps by using [mysqldumpextract](https://github.com/mnalis/mysqldumpextract) (disclosure: I'm the author of the script)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the dump file and you need to restore only single table,
i have created both linux and windows scripts to restore the specific tables from the dump file:

linux (bash script):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Where to restore
db_host='localhost'
db_name='adhoctuts'
db_user='root'
db_pass='Adhoctuts2018#'

dump_file='/root/scripts/dump_ignore.sql'

# Associative table list array as source_table=>destination_table pairs
declare -A tbl_list=( ["tbl1"]="restored_tbl1" ["tbl2"]="restored_tbl2")

for tbl in "${!tbl_list[@]}"
do
    echo "Restore $tbl to ${tbl_list[$tbl]}"
    # extract the content between drop table and Table structure for, also replace the table name
    sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'$tbl'`/,/\/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `'$tbl'` ENABLE KEYS \*\/;/p' $dump_file > tbl.sql
    sed -i 's/`'$tbl'`/`'${tbl_list[$tbl]}'`/g' tbl.sql
    mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p"$db_pass" $db_name < tbl.sql
    rm -f tbl.sql
done
```

windows script (bat):

```
%= Define the database and root authorization details =% 
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set db_host=192.168.70.138
set db_name=adhoctuts
set db_user=adhoctuts
set db_pass=Adhoctuts2018#

set dump_file=dump_ignore.sql

set tbl_cnt=2
set source_table[1]=tbl1
set destination_table[1]=restored_tbl1
set source_table[2]=tbl2
set destination_table[2]=restored_tbl2

set i=1
:loop   
    set src=!source_table[%i%]!
    set dest=!destination_table[%i%]!
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `%src%`"^<"%dump_file%"') do set /a start=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "ALTER TABLE `%src%` ENABLE KEYS"^<"%dump_file%"') do set /a end=%%a
    (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%dump_file%"') do (

    set "line=%%b "
     IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO( !line:%src%=%dest%!
     )
    )>"tbl.sql"

    mysql -h %db_host% -u %db_user% -p"%db_pass%" %db_name% < "tbl.sql"
    del /f "tbl.sql"
    if %i% equ %tbl_cnt% goto :eof
    set /a i=%i%+1
goto loop
```

put your table_name in tbl_list array, in your case both the original and destination table names are the same.

I have also created separate tutorial for MySQL selective/exceptional tasks. You may check if needed:

https://youtu.be/8fWQbtIISdc

https://adhoctuts.com/mysql-selective-exceptional-permissions-and-backup-restore/

Answer (score 0):

Step1: create a user who has privilege to read / write only that particular drop table in the database.

Step2: restore forcefully from your backup (.sql ) file by logging that user .

Step3: Now check database and that table.